# "List of close voters is only viewable by users with the close/reopen votes privilege" is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[image]

The list is viewable by anyone, including anonymous users, in the edit history.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75318083/revisions

Edit: This has been marked as bydesign and flagged as a duplicate - but both of these actions are mistaken. This issue is about the incorrect message that the  "List of close voters is only viewable by users with the close/reopen votes privilege". It is visible by other users in the edit history, so this message is misleading at least.

Comment: [By design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340340/names-of-close-voters-are-not-visible-in-the-post-notice-but-in-the-revision-his) apparently.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This is about the incorrect and misleading message shown to users with the close privilege.

Comment: The list *in the close notice* the very one *right next to the message* is indeed only visible to users with close/reopen privilege. The claim isn't made *in general*. It applies to the element you currently see - one marked with a crossed out eye symbol.

Comment: @VLAZ that's your interpretation, but the message does not say it's referring to only the list in this instance - it can easily be interpreted to mean everywhere, which is not the case. Indeed, what it the purpose of telling someone this specific list is not visible, when it is visible with one more click?

Comment: It's very much by design that the list of close voters in the close notice is not shown to all users, particularly the question author. Yes, it would be more accurate to say something there like "(The list of close voters is only displayed here to users with the cast close and reopen votes privilege who are not the question author.)" It's not clear to me that the additional accuracy there is worth making a change, given that it's relatively difficult to get SE to change things.

Comment: If it's really your intent that this question be specifically about the wording and/or accuracy of the notation regarding the visibility of the list of close voters that's shown in the closed post notification, then please [edit] your question to make it more clear and explicit that's the case. It is clear from other people's actions on this question that is not how everyone reading it has interpreted the question.

Comment: In other words, I'd be willing to reopen this, but it's been fairly clearly demonstrated that the intent of the question is unclear *as it's currently written*, given that about 40% of the people reading it understood it to be different than specifically calling out the accuracy of that statement in the closed question post notice.

Comment: @Makyen I've already edited to add a clarification earlier. The title has been `"message" is incorrect` from the start, with a screenshot of the message in the body. Anyway I give up now.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip,  it looks like you want "feature-request" instead of "bug". I'd recommend reading corresponding tag guidance and [edit] the question to re-tag, include your proposal and good reasoning why it is important for the site.

Comment: So, can someone confirm that that edit banner in the history is visible to users that can view the edit history, but can't close-vote?

Comment: @Cerbrus you can open the link while not logged in.

Comment: I agree that it is a bug. Remove that "List of close voters etc. etc." line from the message box and nothing of relevance is lost, it is essentially fluff. Why it is even mentioned there to begin with, I do not know.

Comment: @Gimby transparency. Also, users who single-handedly closed a post can be pinged.

Comment: Also visible from the '[Timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75318083/timeline)' Button as "*2023-02-02 02:54:18Z - history - closed - User1 / User2 / User3 -  Not suitable for this site*", (+ Links on the 3 Users), always has been... (Myself = 0.6k-Rep, logged in.)

Comment: @VLAZ I stick to it being fluff. Transparency is good when transparency is required. Here it is just a weird message.